# Importing models in cannon.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, cannon.js

I am trying to import an obj file into my cannon.js environment. I am currently using three.js to import the file and define and using this mesh to define a cannon body shape. My goal is to render a vertebrate but all I can get are a bunch of boxes. Can some one please give me more insight for defining the cannon body better? Here is the code I am working on along with the output snapshot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>cannon.js - constraints demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../build/cannon.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/cannon.demo.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/Stats.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/smoothie.js"></script>
     <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/build/three.module.js";
        import { GUI } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/dat.gui@0.7.7/build/dat.gui.module.js";
        import { TrackballControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js";
        import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
        import { STLLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js";
        import { OBJLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";

        /**
         * In this demo, we demonstrate some constraint types. Constraints
         * removes degrees of freedom from bodies and forces them to move in
         * a way defined by the constraint.
         */

        var demo = new CANNON.Demo()
        demo.addScene("lock",function(){
            var world = setupWorld(demo);
            world.solver.iterations = 20;
            world.gravity.set(0,0,-10);
            var size = 0.5;
            var boxShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(size,size,size));
            var mass = 1;
            var space = 0.1*size;

            
      // Sphere chain
      /*demo.addScene("Sphere chain",function(){
          var size = 0.5;
          var dist = size*2+0.12;
          var world = setupWorld(demo);
          //world.solver.setSpookParams(1e20,3);
          //var sphereShape = new CANNON.Sphere(size);
          //var mass = 1;
          //var lastBody = null;
         // var N = 20;
         // world.solver.iterations = N; // To be able to propagate force throw the chain of N spheres, we need at least N solver iterations.
         // for(var i=0; i<N; i++){*/
            // Create a new body
            demo.addScene("Sphere chain",function(){
          var size = 0.5;
          var dist = size*2+0.12;
          var world = setupWorld(demo);
            const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF })
            const loader = new OBJLoader();

         loader.load("resources/Model_8_8.obj", function(object) {
          const geo = object.children[0].geometry;
          const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material)
           const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object.children[0]);
            const width = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
            const height = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y;
            const depth = boundingBox.max.z - boundingBox.min.z;
            const center = new THREE.Vector3();
            boundingBox.getCenter(center);
            const sphereShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2))
           /* let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
           geometry.setAttribute('position', mesh.geometry.getAttribute('position'));

            geometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry); 
           //if using import statement  
            //geometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry);  

            let position = geometry.attributes.position.array;  
           let geomFaces = geometry.index.array;   

          const points = [];  
          const faces = [];  

        for(var i = 0; i < position.length; i += 3){  
       points.push(new CANNON.Vec3(position[i], position[i+1], position[i+2]));  
        }  

       for(var i = 0; i < geomFaces.length; i += 3){  
        faces.push(geomFaces[i], geomFaces[i+1], geomFaces[i+2]);  
          }  


        var sphereShape =  new CANNON.ConvexPolyhedron(points,faces);*/  
        // create a box shape without using indices
     //   Create a Cannon.js body to represent the spine
        var mass = 1;
          var lastBody = null;
         var N = 3;
          world.solver.iterations = N; // To be able to propagate force throw the chain of N spheres, we need at least N solver iterations.
          for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
         var spherebody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: i===0 ? 0 : mass });
         spherebody.addShape(sphereShape);
            spherebody.position.set(0,0,(N-i)*dist);
            spherebody.velocity.x = i;
            world.addBody(spherebody);
            demo.addVisual(spherebody);

            // Connect this body to the last one added
            var c;
            if(lastBody!==null){
              world.addConstraint(c = new CANNON.DistanceConstraint(spherebody,lastBody,dist));
            }

            // Keep track of the lastly added body
            lastBody = spherebody;
          }
        })
        });
    })

      function setupWorld(demo){
        // Create world
        var world = demo.getWorld();
        world.gravity.set(0,0,-40);
        world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
        world.solver.iterations = 10;

        // ground plane
        var groundShape = new CANNON.Plane();
        var groundBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
        groundBody.addShape(groundShape);
        groundBody.position.set(0,0,1);
        world.addBody(groundBody);
        demo.addVisual(groundBody);

        world.quatNormalizeFast = false;
        world.quatNormalizeSkip = 0;

        return world;
      };
    

      demo.start();
    

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kfwm.png)